# Number of contents created by a user in a organic group

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am using organic groups. I have an organic group called A and its group content B.
Users have subscribed to group A and created  content for content type B.

Now, I created a view of users.
There are three columns. 
One for the usernames.Second one for the uid. And in the third one I want to show the number of nodes of type B created by a user.
There is a contextual filter for organic group A.

I am unable to craete the view. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use the [rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) or the [user points module](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints), this is relatively simple. I don't think it's possible using only views.

I would add an integer field to User and have a rule

```
Event: After Saving New Content
Condition: Entity is of type > Content Type B
Action: Calculate a value > Input 1 = site:current user:field / Operator + / Input 2 = 1
```

Then display that field in your view.

User points is another option but is unnecessary if you already use rules.